# Retrieving images from zend framework 2 session

Tags: php, session, zend-framework2, session-variables

In zend framework 2 , I upload my images and then it  ask for login after login my page redirects to same image page but how can I get back that images that was uploaded earlier.

Through session can i retrieve those images. I don't know the procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before redirect to login page from image page you have to save uploaded image to temporary file location with session id and when you back you can easily get that image from temporary location by session ID.